# Java Graphics Dispose Method

Tags: java, graphics, 2d-games

I am wondering about a piece of code:

```
public void render()
{
    BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();

    if(bs == null)
    {
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }

    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}
```

Render is in a Game Loop.

In the book I am reading, it says I need to call dispose here. I don't really understand why. Isn't it overwriting g every time render loops anyway.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#dispose()) is should be done for performance reasons. It will be disposed by itself through the garbage collector if all referances are released.

You're asking:

> Isn't it overwriting g every time render loops anyway.

Well, in your case you create a *new* `Graphics` object every time you inquire for a graphics context. Therefore, the dispose should be called as if it is only called once, since every instance is an isolated case.

Comment: Well I understand why we use dispose(), but what confuses me is why we need to dispose after every iteration of the loop. Since the data at g gets overwritten after every iteration anyway, wouldn't it be more efficient to just dispose at the end, once the loop has ended?

Comment: I mentioned that render is in a game loop.

basically loops until a certain condition is met. i.e character dies.

Comment: Wait, so can you tell me if this is correct? A new graphics context is being created every time, so even though g no longer refers to the old context, the old data may not be collected immediately, so it is better to just get rid of it right away. –  user2776326 2 mins ago

Answer (score 0):

Each `Graphics` object uses system resources, and these should be released. It's much the same as needing to call `close()` on an `InputStream` that you have opened.

If you don't do that, there is code in the `finalize()` method of the object that will return the resource. But it's a known issue in Java that `finalize()` may be called very late, or not at all, and therefore those resources will never be cleared. This can cause the program to stop working at some point when it runs out of resources.

You may be thinking that since at the end of `render()`, the variable `g` goes out of scope, it will be garbage-collected anyway. But it's merely becomes a candidate for collection. Objects that have a finalizer are not collected very quickly - the finalizer has to run before the object is completely removed. And in any case, garbage collection takes care of memory allocation, not other system resources.

This is explained in short in the [documentation of the `dispose()` method itself](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#dispose()).

---

Note that [the documentation for `BufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html#getDrawGraphics()) tells you that each time it is called, it **creates a graphic context**. That is, you are not getting the same object each time - it's a new object for every call of `getDrawGraphics()`.

Comment: Well I understand why we use dispose(), but what confuses me is why we need to dispose after every iteration of the loop. Since the data at g gets overwritten after every iteration anyway, wouldn't it be more efficient to just dispose at the end, once the loop has ended?

Comment: @user2776326 I added a bit about that.

Comment: Wait, so can you tell me if this is correct?

A new graphics context is being created every time, so even though g no longer refers to the old context, the old data may not be collected immediately, so it is better to just get rid of it right away.

Comment: More or less, but the problem is not the fact that it may not be collected immediately, but the fact that it uses system resources, which should *always* be cleaned up by whoever allocated them, unlike heap memory. You are not supposed to trust the `finalize()` method as it may never be called.

Comment: Ok, I guess I kinda assumed that by making g no longer point to the object it would just disappear, but really the object still exists somewhere in memory until finalize is called.